# What is the correct way to static link libc?

Tags: gcc, linker

I've seen a bunch of questions here and on other forums where the suggestion is to use `-static` or sometimes even `-static -static-libgcc` along with the compile arguments. This never works on Alpine, but woks fine on Ubuntu and Fedora.

I wrote a simple hello-world program in C, then had is compiled as `gcc -static test.c`. And the resulting binary still lights up `ldd`. See,

```
$ gcc -s test.c -static
$ ldd ./a.out
    /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f043eae8000)

$ file ./a.out
./a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

Running the same on Ubuntu shows:

```
$ gcc -s test.c -static                   
$ file ./a.out 
./a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=bf6bfa1c78c541ae4e81586bcd050923bca9e34a, stripped
```

What is the correct and consistent way to static link libc itself on any platform? Is this something to do with the way GCC itself is compiled?

Comment: It seems this problem is specific to musl-libc, would you agree? Perhaps the title should be modified accordingly.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart After looking at the answer, I think the problem seems a bit more involved than Alpine or Ubuntu. So I guess the title is correct. I've added the right answer with examples and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ubuntu binary isn't PIE-enabled. If you pass `-no-pie` to GCC on Alpine, its binary will similarly not be PIE-enabled, but then it will be statically linked as you want.

Comment: Why are PIE and static linking related?

Comment: I agree.  I don't think that static linking should be unable to accept PIC libraries or code.  In fact, such things would be preferable for a no-MMU embedded system.  Seems like very very bad GCC design if it is assuming -no-pie == static linking and -fpic == dynamic linking.

Answer (score 5):

I'm answering my own question here for those who naively came here searching on keywords like `static link libc` or something.

If this is for MSVC, your only option is `/MT` or `/MTd`. But if you came here looking for GCC, welcome to the position independent code rabbit hole.

There are several variations of GCC floating around that are patched for specific targets or patched just because they can be. So if you have, say GCC version 6.0 and expect your command line arguments to generate same behaviour, you could be a victim of some bad patch work.

Some versions of GCC as in this question enforce position independent executable (`-fPIE -pie`) and silently ignore the `-static` option as seen in this example. I wonder if this should be reported as a bug to Alpine maintainers. To force it to ignore PIE, pass `-no-pie` to your GCC.

```
$  gcc -no-pie -static test.c
```

And if you do

```
$ file ./a.out
/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1: ./a.out: Not a valid dynamic program
```

For details of how `fPIE` and `static` read these [slides](https://www.openbsd.org/papers/asiabsdcon2015-pie-slides.pdf) from OpenBSD.

Answer (score 1):

You may be building just fine and it looks more like a bug in `file`. See this bug report:
https://bugs.astron.com/view.php?id=93

> Summary: 0000093: file incorrectly recognizes -static-pie binaries

I had the same issue when building QEMU but I was told of the above:
https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/merge_requests/21214#note_156907